# How to get raw frame data from AVFrame.data[] and AVFrame.linesize[] without specifying the pixel format?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

I get the general idea that the `frame.data[]` is interpreted depending on which pixel format is the video (RGB or YUV). But is there any general way to get all the pixel data from the frame? I just want to compute the hash of the frame data, without interpret it to display the image.

According to AVFrame.h:

```
uint8_t* AVFrame::data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
```

pointer to the picture/channel planes.

```
int AVFrame::linesize[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
```

For video, size in bytes of each picture line.

Does this mean that if I just extract from `data[i]` for `linesize[i]` bytes then I get the full pixel information about the frame?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`linesize[i]` contains stride for the `i`-th plane.

To obtain the whole buffer, use the function from `avcodec.h`

```
/**
 * Copy pixel data from an AVPicture into a buffer, always assume a
 * linesize alignment of 1. */   
int avpicture_layout(const AVPicture* src, enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
                 int width, int height,
                 unsigned char *dest, int dest_size);
```

Use

```
int avpicture_get_size(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height);
```

to calculate the required buffer size.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for :D btw, does plane means one color channel such as R/G/B or Y/U/V? I tried to search for the definition, but with these keywords I didn't get much information.

Comment: How come we manually copy ,without `avpicture_layout`, such as `for(number of vertical lines[]){ memory copy upto linesize to a buffer and increment buffer pointer by linesize }` will do the job??

Comment: I think you can typecast `AVFrame` to `AVPicture` here, since `AVFrame` contains the same fields as `AVPicture` See also strict aliasing rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Answer (score 1):

`avpicture_*` API is deprecated. Now you can use `av_image_copy_to_buffer()`  and `av_image_get_buffer_size()` to get image buffer.

You can also avoid creating new buffer memory like above (`av_image_copy_to_buffer()`) by using `AVFrame::data[]` with the size of each array/plane can be get from `av_image_fill_plane_sizes()`. Only do this if you clearly understand the pixel format.

Find more here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__picture.html